# what is the .pst file size

Tags: microsoft-outlook

we need a ms outlook database file size

Comment: Right click the PST> properties? We need more info or this will be closed...

Comment: Usually too large.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Locate your PST file](http://www.ehow.com/how_5951833_locate-outlook-pst-file.html).
2. Right-click it and select Properties.